# How do I change the file endings for either windows or mac file in linux?

Tags: php, windows, linux, macos, line-endings

When I save a TSV file in windows from excel, it uses the line ending of \r or \015 (octal) which shows up in vi as ^M.

When I save a TSV file on the Mac from excel, it uses the line ending of \r\n or \015\012 (octal) which shows up in vi as ^M.

How do I handle changing the line endings on both files without adding extra blank lines but still maintaining linux compatible line endings?

I am currently using exec() in PHP to run the following:

If I use:

```
cat {FILE} | tr -d "\015" > {NEW_FILE}
```

or

```
cat {FILE} | tr -d "\r" > {NEW_FILE}
```

Works for Windows files but Mac files fail. (removes all line endings)

If I use:

```
cat {FILE} | tr "\015" "\012" > {NEW_FILE}
```

or

```
cat {FILE} | tr "\r" "\n" > {NEW_FILE}
```

Works for Mac files but Windows files fail. (creates blank lines)

Any ideas how to handle either within the same routine?

Comment: Tried **sed** ? `sed -e 's/$/\r/' unix-format.txt > win-format.txt`

Comment: It will work for Windows, but does not work for Mac. I need a solution that will work for either file.

Comment: Well, you can try a script that reads the first line + 1 char and see if it ends with \r or \r\n and then handle accordingly within your own 'converter code'. Like this you can stick to pure PHP and no 3rd party dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an elegant solution for this problem. In my PHP script I created the following:

```
$results = exec("cd $directory; grep -Pl $'\r\n' $filename");
if($results == $filename) {
    // Windows File (default)
    exec("cd $directory; cat $filename | tr -d '\015' > $tmpfile; mv $tmpfile $filename");      
} else {
    // MAC File
    exec("cd $directory; cat $filename | tr '\r' '\n' > $tmpfile; mv $tmpfile $filename");  
}
```

I am open to improvements if someone has one.

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix for windows files and mac2unix for mac files.

Comment: Again... I don't have access to those utilities on the server. They are not installed and cannot be.